# Why does this list comprehension only "sometimes" work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Update: Determined that the iteration was happening over the wrong variable

I am writing a script to parse the "hostname" object from json data, and using list comprehensions only "sometimes" works.  I've seen this behavior before when I was more new to Python, however now that I am seeing it again this doesn't make sense; either the list comprehension should work or it should not, without ambiguity.

Specifically, the list comprehension for the variable parsed_data2_hostnames doesn't work, which is an exact replica of the properly working list comprehension for the variable parsed_data_hostnames.  Firstly, you can see that the list comprehension for variable parsed_data_hostnames works perfectly fine, and I am able to get a response, therefore this tells me the structure of the list comprehension is intact.  Secondly, if I convert the failing list comprehension into a "normal" for loop, then the logic works!  This is further evidence that the list comprehension is intact, yet for some reason it still doesn't work.

This doesn't work...

```
parsed_data_hostnames = [i['hostname'] for i in parsed_data['resources']]
# parsed_data2_hostnames = []
# for i in parsed_data2_hostnames:
#     parsed_data2_hostnames = i['hostname']
parsed_data2_hostnames = [i['hostname'] for i in parsed_data2['resources']]
print(len(parsed_data_hostnames), type(parsed_data_hostnames))
print(len(parsed_data2_hostnames), type(parsed_data2_hostnames))
```

Output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jlobianc/PycharmProjects/get_cs_managed_nodes/venv/json_training.py", line 146, in 
parsed_data2_hostnames = [i['hostname'] for i in parsed_data2['resources']]
File "/Users/jlobianc/PycharmProjects/get_cs_managed_nodes/venv/json_training.py", line 146, in 
parsed_data2_hostnames = [i['hostname'] for i in parsed_data2['resources']]
KeyError: 'hostname'

But this does...

```
parsed_data_hostnames = [i['hostname'] for i in parsed_data['resources']]
parsed_data2_hostnames = []
for i in parsed_data2_hostnames:
    parsed_data2_hostnames = i['hostname']
# parsed_data2_hostnames = [i['hostname'] for i in parsed_data2['resources']]
print(len(parsed_data_hostnames), type(parsed_data_hostnames))
print(len(parsed_data2_hostnames), type(parsed_data2_hostnames))
```

Output:

5000 <class 'list'>
0 <class 'list'>

Edit: Verification that the hostname key actually exists in the aforementioned json data (off unix based OS)...

```
with open('/Users/[name_omitted]/cs_results_parsed_2.json', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as outf:
    json.dump(parsed_data2, outf, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Off my MacOS cmd line...

```
[hostname_omitted]:venv [name_omitted]$ jq '.resources[].hostname' ~/cs_results_parsed_2.json | wc -l
    2243

(venv) [name_omitted]:venv [name_omitted]$ grep hostname ~/cs_results_parsed_2.json | more
            "hostname": "SIN-L-1007198",
```

[omitted the rest of the grep output]

Comment: In one version of your code, you're looping on `parsed_data2`. In the other, you're looping on `parsed_data2_hostnames` which is the empty list you had just created.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  I am now getting the same error.  Would love to mark you down as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blckknght stated, in my second "working" example, I was incorrectly iterating over parsed_data2_hostnames instead of parsed_data2.  Once I corrected this mistake, I verified I am getting the same keyerror issue.

Since my problem of parsing that json data is a completely separate issue, I'll close this.  Thanks Blckknght.